# Canon printer extremely slow

Tags: printing, 21.04, canon

I have a Canon Pixma MG6450 connected through the wireless network to my Ubuntu 21.04 system. The driver was downloaded from Canon's website. It uses a bash script to install itself.

Printing is very slow, at about 1 page per hour. The same document can be printed from my Windows PC in less than a minute. This delay seems independent of software: it's very slow whether I'm printing a PDF using evince, a diagram created in Gimp, or a bash script printed from gedit.

What steps can I take to diagnose where the bottleneck is?

Comment: Read `man lpstat lpadmin;man -k cups`. Point a browser to `http://localhost:631`. Read `man journalctl`, do `sudo journalctl  -b 0 -u cups`. Look at `/var/log/cups/*`.

Comment: 1 page per hour!!! Give what you get from the `driverless` command.

Comment: @waltinator thanks, I will read all that info.

Comment: @brian_p I get `ERROR: ippfind (PID 80950) stopped with status 1!`

Comment: @k314159 The Pixma MG6450 is an AirPrint printer. (You can check this). The `driverless` utility is intended for finding AirPrint printers. The message says none are found. That is unexpected and worrying. Try `ippfind`.

Comment: @brian_p thanks. `ippfind` does not output anything. In desperation, I deleted the printer using the GNOME settings, and then tried to reinstall it using the driver downloaded from Canon. It couldn't find the printer on the network and didn't allow me to enter its IP address manually. I then installed it using the GNOME settings again. I then tried printing and it again printed slowly, but much faster than before, at about 3 minutes per page, which is just about liveable.

Comment: @k314159 `ippfind` cannot find a printer that is known to do ipp? Possibilities: printer settings. Access printer with `http://IP`. Network problems. BTW, you do not need the Canon drivers when things are working correctly.